# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException:

Tags: android-studio, gradle, teamcity

I am trying to run a clean build of a simple Android Studio project using gradle in TeamCity.

It runs a few tasks, but then stops and returns this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.     
com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 8 exceptions 
were raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.
```

It doesn't get past this error, and can't successfully do a clean build of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I will just leave an answer in hopes it will help you in some ways.

What is your full project directory? It maybe caused due to long path names.

Try restarting your ADB, Project, up to the point where even a PC restart may work

Do you have enough privileges to and on the directory?

Try adding this to your build.gradle

```
android {
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

Lastly try to rebuild your project by going to Build > Rebuild project. Or even do a clean by Build > clean project.

Let me know if anything works. Happy Coding :)

Comment: The directory is in C:\BuildAgent\work\xxxxx\ . It is being pulled down from a GitHub repository from a Build Agent in TeamCity, which is running inside a container. Additionally, it is running on a Windows 10 VM. THe Github repository is public so I don't think it is a problem as it runs a bunch of tasks before this error. I added that to the build.gradle and got another error: Could not find method android() for arguments

Comment: I suppose I am out of options here then. Are your build tools and everything up to date? Or matching the project? You said it was a Git repo right? Does the gradle version and everything match your environment?

Comment: Yes. I believe I have everything correctly installed.

Comment: which ```build.gradle```, ```<project root>/build.gradle``` or ```app/build.gradle```